# How to perform analysis of Copper and carbon nanotube interconnects in CMOS using LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, spice

How is it possible to model interconnect as that of Copper or CNT in a CMOS inverter to analyze the delay and power using LTSpice?

Comment: LTSpice is a circuit simulator. If you can characterise your interconnects in terms of circuit parameters, resistance, capacitance to substrate, inductance, then you can put those into your model.

Comment: Modelling physical circuits is not easy business. Either you know how to model, or you have a model to work with, which needs implementation. The former requires knowledge of both the simulator and the physical world (of the device), the latter is mostly the simulator. So which one is it?

Comment: Modelling R,L,C parameters for both Cu and CNT and then observe the delay or power. Yeah..realised this one is more complicated.